# jquery selection method

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
   <script>
            $("*", document.body).each(function () {//is document.body a context?
                var parentTag = $(this).parent().get(0).tagName;
                //Above statement is only selecting the body tag why?

                $(this).prepend(document.createTextNode(parentTag + " > "));
            });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there any reason for selecting only body tag in the above script?Also is document.body a context?since document.body is not quoted will it be a context?

Comment: It doesn't: http://jsbin.com/anumip/1/

Comment: Works fine for me as well: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/eVqp3/.

Comment: Regarding your second question, any element can be a context, including `document.body`.

Comment: @Felix Kling than how is the body tag getting selected also since document.body is not quoted will that be a context?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi than how is the body tag getting selected also since document.body is not quoted will that be a context?

Comment: I don't know why you think it is selected. It isn't.

Comment: @MaizerePathak, the `<body>` element is not selected, but your call to `parent()` returns it from its first-level children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope these are the ansers you are looking for

```
> Is there any reason for selecting only body tag in the above script?
```

It doesnt select only the Bodytag, if you run this code in Chrome you will see the tags

```
 $("*" ,document.body).each(function (idx, elem) {
 console.log(elem);
 });
```

> Also is document.body a context?

Yes, it is here is a line to the [API LINK](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1)

> since document.body is not quoted will it be a context?

Yes, it is here is a line to the [API LINK](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1)